# Regex xml validation

Tags: regex

I am trying to write a regex for satisfying all conditions below:

1. numbers separated by commas
2. d{n}:d{n} where n =1- 13
3. Ex : 1,2,4:5,3,22:44,66,666,777:888
4. Should not end with , or :
5. Should not start with , or :
6. should not allow only , or :
7. should not allow multiple ,s or :s

I found a few answers where i could build on but those allowed , and :

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far!

Comment: Please try to clarify; it's almost impossible to understand what you are asking for.

Comment: there should be a language tag

Comment: What does this have to do with XML?

Comment: I had tried a few approaches : ^(([0-9]:[0-9])|([0-9],[0-9])?,{0,1}(?<=,)([0-9]))|\*|[0-9]$ was the one which comes closest to answering my qs for single digit entries for ex. I am trying to build it for multiple digits. However the xml file doesnt get deployed when i use this

Comment: Also tried:    ((\d(:|,)\d),?d?)+|d+|\*  but this doesnt solve my requirements either as it allows 12:2 .

Comment: I am using it as a part of XML tag. Realize that it is not XML specific

Answer (score 1):

This is what you need

```
^(\d{1,13}([:,]\d{1,13})*)$
```

works [here](http://regexpal.com/)

Comment: Thanks Anirudha but this is not what I am looking for. I want teh range specified to have a number of specific lengths only such as 12:24, 6666, 3333-9999 etc